# how to access the detected object's name in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to access the detected objects name in a live stream from this code,

https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app/blob/master/object_detection_app.py

I have tried the following code

```
print [category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5]
```

The output looks like:

[image]

How can I access the person data?

Comment: i figured it out,visualization_utils.py file got the class name

Answer (score 1):

Get the class name from visualization_utils.py file, then you can easily get your data.